# package error when building spfx webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, webpack

I am using the following breadcrum [sample](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-breadcrumb). To reproduce the error use command: `gulp serve`

Error I  got:

> ./src/extensions/siteBreadcrumb/SiteBreadcrumbApplicationCustomizer.ts
>   Module parse failed: C:\Users\username\Projets\26_name\Code\Breadcrumb\sp-dev-fx-extensions\samples\react-application-breadcrumb\src\extensions\siteBreadcrumb\SiteBreadcrumbApplicationCustomizer.ts Unexpected token (15:16)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | import { ISiteBreadcrumbProps } from './components/ISiteBreadcrumb';
>   |
>   | const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'SiteBreadcrumbApplicationCustomizer';
>   |
>   | /**`

Comment: Keshav , whether  install npm to the solution works perfect? i would suggest create a application customizer by own and use their breadcrumb code this way i think there should not be any error. I have did for My favorites the same way.

Comment: @vinitkumar Yes npm install works correctly,when doing gulp serve that i get the error.

Comment: Can you run `gulp serve-info` and check ?

Comment: So, what's on line 15 of the SiteBreadcrumbApplicationCustomizer.ts file?

Comment: Can you provide more detail around the error - where did it happen, what lines of output were there immediately before the error?  I've cloned the repo, run `npm i` and `gulp serve-info --nobrowser` here with no issues.  What version of gulp do you have installed globally?  What version of NodeJS and npm are you using?

Comment: @MikeInsch I have re-downloaded the sample and the build is done without any error now but when i deploy the latter on my tenant i don't see the breadcrumb

Comment: @GautamSheth it builds without error but i don't see the extension on my site when deployed

Comment: @GautamSheth i got it work,i forgotten to change the cdn link,it works in a developer site but for a modern team site i get this error:

There is no operation handler registered for '{"operation_12":["getItems_21","contextMenuCustomActionSetKeyFacet_321"]}'.